# how can i verify phone number with php

Tags: php

i have a phone number in following format  +923334173333 and now i want to validate this number exactly in the given format and length with php

Comment: I would look at regexlib.com for some regular expressions.

Comment: Are you wanting to verify that the input matches the form of a phone number, or that the input specifies a real live phone number that can be dialed?  If the latter, then you could hookup some sort of VoIP service to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastest way would be

```
function validatePhoneNumber($n)
{
    return strlen($n) == 13 && $n[0] == '+' && ctype_digit(substr($n, 1)) == 13;
}


validatePhoneNumber('+923334173333'); // returns true
```

Comment: Don't you want to check if those 13 digits are numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You would need the rules for all possible types of phone numbers and their limitation in the whole world. I'm uncertain if such list even exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the length with strlen(), and use ctype_digit() in combination with substr() to check that the substring starting after the '+' consists only of digits.